# np.any(np.not_equal(arr, 0), axis=0) vs np.count_nonzero(arr)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with a lot of non-zero values. I got 2 different result when I calculated the total number of non-zero items using:

1)

```
non_zero_weights = np.any(np.not_equal(lr_l1.coef_, 0), axis=0)
new_vocab_size = non_zero_weights.sum()
```

2)

```
np.count_nonzero(lr_l1.coef_)
```

Am I missing something here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct:

```
np.count_nonzero(lr_l1.coef_)
```

In the first option, however, you are not finding the number of non-zero values in the array, but finding out whether there is **at least 1** non-zero value. That is what `np.any()` does.

This should be the following instead:

```
non_zero_weights = np.not_equal(lr_l1.coef_, 0)
new_vocab_size = non_zero_weights.sum()
```

Comment: Cool! it would be great if you add an example for the at least 1 non-zero value?

Comment: If you are talking about finding whether there is at least 1 non-zero value, you can just do `np.any(arr!=0)` with your np.array `arr`. It returns a boolean which is True or False.